# How to make a method return an arbitrary struct using <T> magic in C#?

Tags: c#

Title sums it up.  I want to be able to call

```
Foo f = getStruct<Foo>(..)
```

and have the method create a new Foo object (it would be a struct), populate it, and return it?

Also, what is the < T > type of constructor called?  My google-searches are failing as I'm sure what I should be searching for..

Additionally, I know that all the structs that can be created have a .raw field.  I want to be able to populate that .raw field.

This is essentially what I want to do.

```
    public T getStruct<T>(UInt32 sector) {
        <T> foo = new <T>;

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) foo.raw[i]=0;
        return foo;
    }
```

Where the structs have the form of

```
  StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
  public unsafe struct RunBlock_t {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]  public fixed byte raw[512];
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]  public UInt16 run_id;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(2)]  public UInt16 magic;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(510)]  public UInt16 checksum;
  }
```

The function passes the .raw pointer and the sector to another function which loads that sector from the disk, then byte by byte copies the contents back into .raw

In this way, I can create an arbitrary struct and populate it from disk quickly and simply.  This is not very C# friendly, I know, but there are other external dependencies which require it.

Thnx!

Comment: Are you sure, that this should be struct, not a class?

Comment: Yeah, it's a pointer.  they look like this:     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public unsafe struct RunBlock_t {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]  public fixed byte raw[512];
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]  public UInt16 run_id;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(2)]  public UInt16 magic;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(510)]  public UInt16 checksum;
    }

Comment: How is the `sector` argument used in the initialization?

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if this what you are looking for, but you can make a generic method like this:

```
public static T GetStruct<T>() where T : struct //if T has to be struct
{
    return new T();
    //or return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

**Edit:**

I think you're essentially missing the point that the generic `T` should be known at compile time if you have to use its properties,fields or methods. If you know your `T` will always be `Foo` then you need not make your function generic. You could just do:

```
public Foo getFoo(UInt32 sector)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) foo.raw=0;
    return foo;
}
```

But if you have sub-types for `Foo` then there's a point in making the function generic. Like this or so:

```
public T getStruct<T>(UInt32 sector) where T : Foo
{
    T foo = new T();

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) foo.raw=0;
    return foo;
}
```

Now you can call the function by specifying the type you prefer. But for that you will need the `raw` function defined on `Foo` types. The bottom line is to call any method on an object, it should be known at compile time. Otherwise you will have to use `dynamic` keyword which is a bad idea mostly.

Comment: can you see my edit above? Can I also access entries of the created struct?

Comment: it says foo is undefined..
        public T getStruct<T>(UInt32 sector) where T : struct, new() {
            (T) foo = new T();
            for (int i=0; i<100; i++) foo.raw=0;
            return foo;
        }

Comment: @reza you can extent the code I provided. Your requirement doesnt seem to be clear. What is uint `sector` doing in your function?

Comment: Yes foo is undefined cos compiler doesnt know what is `foo`. In that case you have to explicitly specify what is type `T` in where clause. To do that you would need to have a public base class/abstract class/interface defined with `.raw` method defined on it.

Comment: this code does not work as you can't have the `new()` constraint being used in conjunction with `struct`.

Comment: You can use `default(T)` instead to get an instance of the struct.  But that's not going to let you access a `.raw` field.

Comment: I store data on a sector of an SD card.  The data maps byte for byte to a structed struct.  I want to call  SomeStruct s = getStruct<SomeStruct>(34);  The code loads sector 34 from the disk into a byte[].  It instantiate a new SomeStruct.  SomeStruct is guaranteed to have a .raw entry.  I want then copy 512 bytes from the byte[] to the .raw pointer.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<100; i++) foo.raw=0; This line doesn't make sense. Loop a 100 times over the same field?

Comment: @AlastairPitts thanks for that. I missed the point initially.

Comment: @reza: So your struct only contain a single array? Then why encapsulate it?

Comment: @nawfal I have several structs that all have a public fixed byte raw[512] defined at FieldOffset(0).  How can I create an abstract class that works that way?

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras you can see two sample structs here: http://pastebin.com/LPNUDpZF

Comment: @reza yours is a classic requirement, which should obviously occur in any program. The way to deal with is it create an interface `IFoo` which has `raw` method defined. Then implement `IFoo` on all the structs you are mentioning. This will force all your structs to have a `raw` method on it. Now you can use `IFoo` as a constraint as in my answer, Alastair Pitt's answer and many more. If all the implementation of various `raw` methods are the same, then make `Foo` an abstract base class.

Comment: Please see more to interfaces,inheritance etc. You are essentially looking into basic OOP concepts like polymorphism etc. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to create interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Raw { get; set; }
}
```

and all your structures must implement this interface:

```
public struct Foo:IFoo
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]  public fixed byte raw[512];
    public int Raw { get{return raw;} set{raw = value;} }
}
```

And create Generic method:

```
 public static T GetStructs<T>(UInt32 sector) where T : struct, IFoo
        {
            var foo = new T {Raw = new int[sector]};
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                foo.Raw[i] = 0;
            }
            return foo;
        }
```

To call it use this code:

```
var foo = getStructs<Foo>(32);
```

Comment: And how is looping over the same field 100 times gonna fill a 100 fields?

Comment: Did you listen about yield return? It returns instance of Foo on every loop. Cause Foo is struct - it returns different instances.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanow: So instead of making 1 struct and filling many field, you create many struct wit 1 field.

Comment: This is what I have: http://pastebin.com/CVMrbHcp  it's not giving me any warning I'll test it out and see if it works..

Comment: NO! Interfaces cannot contain fields!  After an hour re-coding everything to use your style. :(

Comment: Interface can contains properties. And structs can. Use Property Raw as getter and setter to your field raw as in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a struct factory.

Here I used a combination of interfaces and contained structs. If the fixed byte struct is common, then I create a struct for that, and enclose it in all the structs I define. You can also set an interface to gain access if needed from generic methods.

Initialization is still handled by the `Activator` object, and I make sure the raw bytes are always initialized by calling the `Initialize()` method in `RawBuffer`.

As an example I initialized two different structs, and counted the ticks it takes to complete the operation.

```
public interface IBlock
{
    RawBuffer Raw { get; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct RawBuffer
{
    public const int Count = 512;
    public const int Size = sizeof(byte) * Count;

    public fixed byte raw[Count];

    public void Initialize()
    {
        fixed (byte* ptr = raw)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                ptr[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = RawBuffer.Size)]
public unsafe struct RunBlock_t : IBlock
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public RawBuffer raw;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt16 run_id; 
    [FieldOffset(2)] public UInt16 magic; 
    [FieldOffset(510)] public UInt16 checksum;

    public RunBlock_t(UInt32 sector)
    {
        raw.Initialize();
        run_id = 0;
        magic = 0;
        checksum = 0;            
    }
    public RawBuffer Raw { get { return raw; } }
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=RawBuffer.Size)]
public unsafe struct RunBlock_s : IBlock
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public RawBuffer raw;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt16 run_id;
    [FieldOffset(2)] public UInt32 soup;
    [FieldOffset(510)] public UInt16 checksum;

    public RunBlock_s(UInt32 sector)
    {
        raw.Initialize();
        run_id = 0;
        soup = 0;
        checksum = 0;            
    }
    public RawBuffer Raw { get { return raw; } }
}

class Program
{

    public static T Factory<T>(UInt32 sector)
        where T : struct, IBlock
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), sector);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var A = Factory<RunBlock_t>(0x20);
        long tic = sw.ElapsedTicks;

        Console.WriteLine("Initilized {0} in {1} cycles", A.GetType().Name, tic);
        // Initilized RunBlock_t in 1524 cycles


        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var B = Factory<RunBlock_s>(0x40);
        tic = sw.ElapsedTicks;

        Console.WriteLine("Initilized {0} in {1} cycles", B.GetType().Name, tic);
        // Initilized RunBlock_s in 722 cycles
    }
}
```

Comment: that's very close to what I want.  The only difference is that the struct has pointers in it, and I want to copy byte by byte data into it.

Comment: @reza, that was not in the original posting. Please edit the question with the full information.

Answer (score 0):

Creating one is fairly easy:

```
public T GetStruct<T>()
{
    T myStruct = (T)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    return myStruct;
}
```

However, if you want to fill it, you won't be able to in a generic method as you are unaware of the components inside, at least not directly. Unless you use reflection... like this:

```
using System.Reflection;

public T GetStruct<T>() where T : struct
{
    T myStruct = (T)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    FieldInfo[] infos = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (FieldInfo info in infos)
    { 
        //Do something to fill the values;
        info.SetValue(myStruct, myValue);
    }

    return myStruct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only return `struct`'s, the adding the [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) `struct` will mean that you can create a new struct without knowing the type.

If you are going to be returning `class`es, then you'll need to add the `new()` constraint.

To guarantee that you have a `.raw` property on the generic type, you can add an interface as a generic constraint.

```
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        int raw { get; set;  }
    }

    public static T GetStruct<T>(UInt32 sector) where T: struct , IMyInterface
    {
        var obj = new T();

        obj.raw = 0;

        return obj;
    }
```

The `obj` will know, due to the `IMyInterface` constraint, that the `raw` property is guaranteed to be on the generic type.